# XSD node "sets"

Tags: xml, powershell, xsd

I have an XML node that can can contain a (required) A child node and an (optional) B child node, or it can contain a (required) Y child node and an (optional) Z child node. But if it contains an A node, it cannot contain a Y or a Z node.
So these are valid

```
<node>
    <a />
    <b />
</node>
<node>
    <a />
</node>
<node>
    <y />
    <z />
</node>
<node>
    <y />
</node>
```

but these are not

```
<node>
    <a />
    <y />
</node>
<node>
    <b />
    <y />
</node>
<node>
    <b />
    <z />
</node>
<node>
    <b />
</node>
```

It doesn't seem like Substitution Groups or Choice Indicators can do the job, and while Element Groups allow me to address the B as allowed peer of A issue, I don't see a way to exclude the Y group if an A group has already been found.

Am I missing something? Or is this a case where I just include all four possible nodes in a group, so my validation fails if there is an M or N node that are never valid, and then I need to write code to do a second level of validation? And if so, is it possible (in PowerShell) to do XSD based validation on a specific node after a `.SelectSingleNode()`? Or is XSD validation limited to use with `$xmlReaderSettings.ValidationType` when converting a string to an `[XML]` type? I guess I could convert my single node back to a string, then reread it with a reader that uses a secondary XSD file, but that seems to be getting messy enough to not be worth the effort, and just writing second pass validation code makes more sense. I prefer the idea of validating this at the XML file level honestly, because then I can easily provide the file name and line number along with the issue in a log, to make XML revision much easier. Any second level validation seems like I lose the original line numbers.

And a related question: I keep seeing reference to XSD 1.1 offering more options. But these posts tend to be 4-5 years old. Is powerShell using XSD 1.1 now, or can it, or are we still waiting on that?

Comment: With reference to your last question; PowerShell uses .NET behind the scenes and there is no .NET implementation of XSD v1.1, just v1 unfortunately. Considering that XSD v1.1 came out in 2012, it's unlikely that XSD v1.1 support will ever be added.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the choice by defining several sequences after it. see the below example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="node" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="a"/>
                                <xs:element name="b" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="y"/>
                                <xs:element name="z" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```